# VB6 form_load pass parameters

Tags: vb6, parameters, form-load

I want to pass a parameter to another form using to the form_load method.

For example,

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal type as integer)

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, an error occurs when I type this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't  :)

But you can load the form, then fill public variables on the form, and then call a sub that you make, or do the processing in the form_show

Answer (score 4):

Another option is a "constructor" method that takes the parameters you want and calls `Me.Show`.
The method can then be called instead of `CustomForm.Show` in the other module.

Comment: +1. This also makes for better design, because it decouples the module from the form.

Answer (score 1):

you do the otherway around

declare a function that takes a form as a parameter and use that;-)

```
public sub mbox(msg as String, frm as Form)
  frm.label1.caption = msg
end Function
```